# 4 random function in specific interval time

Tags: ios

I have 4 function and i want to execute them randomly every 1 second for unlimited time.
This is my code to execute a random function:

```
-(void) Game
{
    int rand = arc4random() % 5;

    switch (rand) {
        case 0:
            [self appearred];
            break;
        case 1:
            [self appearblue];
            break;
        case 2:
            [self appearyellow];
            break;
        case 3:
            [self appeargreen];
            break;
}    
}
```

But how can i repeat this function every 1 second??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try like this

```
 *

-(void) Game
    {
        int rand = (int)arc4random() % 4;

        switch (rand) {
            case 0:
                [self appearred];
                break;
            case 1:
                [self appearblue];
                break;
            case 2:
                [self appearyellow];
                break;
            case 3:
                [self appeargreen];
                break;
        }    
        [self performSelector:@selector(Game) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
    }
```

*

It will call the Game Functions after each second

Answer (score 0):

Just use a NSTimer.

PS : You will not be 100% sure that this will append every 1second.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code which will call `Game` method every 1.0 second. One more thing, in your `Game` method you need to use `% 4` instead of `% 5` to get value between 0 to 3.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(Game)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];

-(void) Game
{
    int rand = (int)arc4random() % 4;

    switch (rand) {
        case 0:
            [self appearred];
            break;
        case 1:
            [self appearblue];
            break;
        case 2:
            [self appearyellow];
            break;
        case 3:
            [self appeargreen];
            break;
    }    
}
```